# PowerShell module design - Export-ModuleMember

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-module

I am building a module that exports a cmdlet that I would like to make available through my profile. The implementation of this cmdlet is spread across multiple implementation files that contain implementation functions I don't want to make publicly available. So I use [Export-ModuleMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember) to hide them.

#### File *get_something.psm1*

```
import-module .\get_something_impl.psm1

function Get-Something {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Get-SomethingImplementation
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-Something
```

I then add *get_something.psm1* to my profile. By exporting only *Get-Something*, all of my implementation functions remain "private".

The issue I'm experiencing is that when using the *Export-ModuleMember* command, I have to import a module in my implementation files every time I need a function inside of it. For example, assume I have a module, person.psm1, with a function, *Get-Person*, that I need to call throughout all of my implementation files. Now I must import *person.psm1* in every single file that I need to call *Get-Person*. This is a result of using *Export-ModuleMember-Function* *Get-Something*. Without it, I would only need to import *person.psm1* once and it would be available.

In essence, *Export-ModuleMember* is not only blocking my implementation to the outside. It's blocking it from my own implementation.

Is this expected and considered a normal aspect of designing PowerShell modules?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This was actually a bit of debate during the development of modules.  Originally, `Export-ModuleMember` was required to export any function.  This became tedious and limiting.  So, by default, all functions from a module are visible, but variables and aliases are not, as long as you've never used `Export-ModuleMember` within the `.PSM1`.

If you use `Export-ModuleMember`, it begins to restrict that list.  It may not be a bad idea to export a smaller number of functions, but you have to use it somewhat carefully.

You can either write:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function a,b,c
```

which exports a few functions.

or

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```

The latter one is equivalent to omitting `Export-ModuleMember` altogether.

You can use more restrictive wildcards if you'd like, but I find that 99% of the time, you don't need to bother with it at all.

The other thing you seem to be asking is how best to handle module dependencies.  Nowadays, it's fairly common to import a module or two when writing a script, just like it's fairly common to include an assembly or two in a C# project.  If you're doing this inside of a module, you can use the `-Global` flag on `Import-Module`, and avoid using `-Force` (which will reload the module).  This makes it a notch more efficient to reuse the module in different functions.  It also makes it less likely to have problems with "cycling" (unloading and reloading) the module, which, unfortunately, many modules do not do well.

The alternative to referencing the module in each function is using a module manifest (`Get-Help New-ModuleManifest`).   Module manifests are very interesting, and required learning for many parts of module development.  If you include a module in the `RequiredModules` list of the Module manifest, it will be automatically loaded before the module is imported (at least in PowerShell 3 and greater).  If you include a module in the `NestedModules` list of the module manifest, it will be loaded as part of the module, and the commands exported by the module will be exported by your module instead.

Module design is a tricky beast, but it's very rewarding to do right.  Best of luck.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "cycling" the module and give an example of how modules don't do it well?  Why is `Import-Module -Global` a magic fix for this?  I believe the issue with "cycling" is covered by the following GitHub issue (but maybe there is more nuances): https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6818#issuecomment-443877176