# Variables I listed to export in my powershell module manifest aren't actually exporting

Tags: powershell, variables, module, export, manifest

I am creating a script module and using a manifest to export script members and set other module properties. I have followed just about every example manifest I've found and even used New-ModuleManifest to create a baseline manifest with the properties I want, I still cannot get the variables I want to export to actually export.

The intention here is to do all declarations in the manifest without having to use `Export-ModuleMember` in the module script.

Here is the script module:

```
#
# Widget.psm1
#

[System.Random]$rGen = New-Object System.Random;
[string]$WidgetBaseName = $null;
[string]$WidgetColor = "Blue";

function Get-WidgetName
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$widgetName,
        [switch]$appendRandomNumber
    )

    if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($WidgetBaseName))
    {
        $widgetName = $WidgetBaseName + $widgetName;
    }

    if ($appendRandomNumber)
    {
        return [string]::Format("{0}{1:D4}", $widgetName, $rGen.Next(10000));
    }
    else
    {
        return $widgetName;
    }
}

function Get-WidgetBlessing()
{
    return [string]::Format("A thousand blessings upon your {0} widget!", $WidgetColor);
}
```

And this is the manifest:

```
#
# Widget.psd1
#

@{

# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest
RootModule = 'Widget.psm1'

# Version number of this module.
ModuleVersion = '0.0.0.1'

# ID used to uniquely identify this module
GUID = 'c4437164-ea47-4148-97ed-48737bd5824d'

# Author of this module
Author = 'Widget Developer'

# Company or vendor of this module
CompanyName = 'Fictional Company Inc.'

# Copyright statement for this module
Copyright = '(c) 2016 Fictional Company. All rights reserved.'

# Description of the functionality provided by this module
Description = 'Widget Module'

# Minimum version of the Windows PowerShell engine required by this module
# PowerShellVersion = ''

# Name of the Windows PowerShell host required by this module
# PowerShellHostName = ''

# Minimum version of the Windows PowerShell host required by this module
# PowerShellHostVersion = ''

# Minimum version of the .NET Framework required by this module
# DotNetFrameworkVersion = ''

# Minimum version of the common language runtime (CLR) required by this module
# CLRVersion = ''

# Processor architecture (None, X86, Amd64) required by this module
# ProcessorArchitecture = ''

# Modules that must be imported into the global environment prior to importing this module
# RequiredModules = @()

# Assemblies that must be loaded prior to importing this module
# RequiredAssemblies = @()

# Script files (.ps1) that are run in the caller's environment prior to importing this module
# ScriptsToProcess = @()

# Type files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
# TypesToProcess = @()

# Format files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
# FormatsToProcess = @()

# Modules to import as nested modules of the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess
# NestedModules = @()

# Functions to export from this module
FunctionsToExport = @( "Get-WidgetName", "Get-WidgetBlessing" )

# Cmdlets to export from this module
# CmdletsToExport = @()

# Variables to export from this module
VariablesToExport = 'WidgetBaseName', 'WidgetColor'

# Aliases to export from this module
AliasesToExport = '*'

# List of all modules packaged with this module
# ModuleList = @()

# List of all files packaged with this module
# FileList = @()

# Private data to pass to the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess
# PrivateData = ''

# HelpInfo URI of this module
# HelpInfoURI = ''

# Default prefix for commands exported from this module. Override the default prefix using Import-Module -Prefix.
# DefaultCommandPrefix = ''

}
```

To check what members get exported, I run the following commands in my PowerShell window:

```
Import-Module Widget
Get-Module -Name Widget | fl
```

This is the output. Note the conspicuous absence of any exported variables.

```
Name              : Widget
Path              : D:\SRE\PowerShell\Widget\Widget.psm1
Description       : Widget Module
ModuleType        : Script
Version           : 0.0.0.1
NestedModules     : {}
ExportedFunctions : {Get-WidgetBlessing, Get-WidgetName}
ExportedCmdlets   : 
ExportedVariables : 
ExportedAliases   :
```

Why is this? I'm using the manifest that New-ModuleManifest generated (`New-ModuleManifest -VariablesToExport WidgetBaseName WidgetColor`). Is that tool broken, or is there something else in the manifest that is causing this behavior?

**UPDATE:**

I added the following line to the end of the module script:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Variable WidgetBaseName, WidgetColor
```

I changed the value of `VariablesToExport` to '*' in the manifest file.

Now when I import the module and run the check as described above, I get this instead:

```
Name              : Widget
Path              : D:\SRE\PowerShell\Widget\Widget.psm1
Description       : Widget Module
ModuleType        : Script
Version           : 0.0.0.1
NestedModules     : {}
ExportedFunctions : 
ExportedCmdlets   : 
ExportedVariables : {WidgetBaseName, WidgetColor}
ExportedAliases   :
```

... where did my exported functions go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Module Design - Export-ModuleMember](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205103/powershell-module-design-export-modulemember)

Comment: Nothing is broken; you must use `Export-ModuleMember`; see the linked duplicate.

Comment: Here is a link that expands on what @briantist is saying: http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/powershell-export-modulemember-vs-export-keys-in-manifest/.  I have never tried to export variables before; the behavior being described in that SO post and this link are definitely counter intuitive IMHO.

Comment: @JasonBoyd that's an excellent article

Comment: I do not agree that this is a duplicate of that other article. That other article only discusses exporting using `Export-ModuleMember` and does not discuss manifests at all.

Is the take-away here that one simply cannot use the manifest to declare which variables to export?

Comment: It sounds like if you want to export anything other than functions you have to specify that by using `Export-ModuleMember` in your module.  Then as long as you have `VariablesToExport = '*'` in your manifest you will export all the variables that you already said you were going to export.  Honestly, I do not understand why it was implemented this way.  This seems like a really bad design decision.  Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: I tried that, adding a call to `Export-ModuleMember` to declare variables to export. Now functions aren't exporting.

Comment: It _sounds_ like if you do not add any `Export-ModuleMember` calls to your module then `Export-ModuleMember -Function *` is implicitly called.  It also _sounds_ as if explicitly calling `Export-ModuleMember` even one time causes the implicit call to `Export-ModuleMember -Function *` to no longer happen.  That is how I understand it after piecing information together from a couple of different posts.  If you explicitly add that line to your module what happens?

Comment: Adding that to the script restores the exported functions. Which is to say, they now show up when I call `Get-Module` etc. Looks like I'm stuck using `Export-ModuleMember` as a workaround. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So for the sake of completeness and for anybody that lands on this question in the future I am going to sum up the conversation we had in the comments to the OP's question.

All functions are exported from a module by default, no other members exhibit this behavior.  It is as if `Export-ModuleMember -Function *` is implicitly called from within the module.  You can then further restrict what functions are exported via the `ExportedFunctions` key in the module manifest, e.g. `ExportedFunctions : {Get-WidgetBlessing, Get-WidgetName}`.

If you want to export variables or aliases you have to explicitly add a call to `Export-ModuleMember -Variable <what you want to export>` or `Export-ModuleMember -Alias <what you want to export>` in your module.  However, once you have added an explicit call to `Export-ModuleMember` the implicit call to `Export-ModuleMember -Function *` no longer happens.  You have to remember to add `Export-ModuleMember -Function *` to your module explicitly if you add even one other explicit call to `Export-ModuleMember` or else your functions will no longer continue to be exported.

Comment: I actually prefer to do it the other way around: call `Export-ModuleMember` to restrict what gets exported from the `psm1` module, and then leave those fields as `'*'` in the manifest. This means I can manage all the module's names of things in *one file*, instead of jumping back and forth as much.

Answer (score 3):

Actually noticed the valid response is opposite to documentation.

From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-6)

**FunctionsToExport**

> Specifies the functions to export from this module, for best
>   performance, do not use wildcards and do not delete the entry, use an
>   empty array if there are no functions to export. **By default, no
>   functions are exported**. You can use this key to list the functions
>   that are exported by the module. The module exports the functions to
>   the caller's session state. The caller's session state can be the
>   global session state or, for nested modules, the session state of
>   another module. When chaining nested modules, all functions that are
>   exported by a nested module will be exported to the global session
>   state unless a module in the chain restricts the function by using the
>   FunctionsToExport key. If the manifest exports aliases for the
>   functions, this key can remove functions whose aliases are listed in
>   the AliasesToExport key, but this key cannot add function aliases to
>   the list. Example: FunctionsToExport = @("function1", "function2",
>   "function3")

**VariablesToExport**

> Specifies the variables that the module exports to the caller's
>   session state. Wildcard characters are permitted. **By default, all
>   variables ('*') are exported**. You can use this key to restrict the
>   variables that are exported by the module. The caller's session state
>   can be the global session state or, for nested modules, the session
>   state of another module. When you are chaining nested modules, all
>   variables that are exported by a nested module will be exported to the
>   global session state unless a module in the chain restricts the
>   variable by using the VariablesToExport key. If the manifest also
>   exports aliases for the variables, this key can remove variables whose
>   aliases are listed in the AliasesToExport key, but this key cannot add
>   variable aliases to the list. Example: VariablesToExport =
>   @('$MyVariable1', '$MyVariable2', '$MyVariable3')